# Windows Task Scheduler - See line breaks in task description

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I know this is a silly question, but it's really bothering me.

I'm using Windows Task Scheduler for a process, what I do is create several task from a PowerShell, in each task's description I write some information, like an ID, a code..., and each of this "entries" I add them with a line break.

The "problem" is that in the preview that shows when you select the task the text is presented without line breaks, making it very annoying to read.

Does anyone knows any way of changing this behaviour?

I add some images to better explain the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried to paste the following pattern via clipboard (one after one from notepad++) and the issue remains the same:

```
 <CR>
 <CRLF>
 <LF>
```

There is no hint in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/taskschedulerschema-description-registrationinfotype-element) that "description" would accept any kind of metacharacters. Adding a `<br />` inside XML is not working: You cannot import this task anymore. Adding a `&#10;&#13;` inside XML is just like adding `<CRLF>`. Powershell [doku](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps) also says "description" is string.

It seems to be a problem of the GUI.